# How do I stop/repair this damage to my dining table?

Tags: damage

I bought this dining table about 3 years back. I started to see some kind of damage (growing) on the table. Any idea what this is and how I can stop it (treatment options)?

[image]

Comment: It looks more like danage ftom something hot ir wet left on it, like glass tumbler. What makes you think its growth

Comment: I take *growing* here to mean the damage is getting worse, not that it's a life-form, @RohitGupta

Comment: Your table is a combination of poor products/time. The products = lesser quality types of seals and/or varnishes. Without viewing the table underneath or a pan view, my guesstimate is the wood used, in making the table, is of a more lighter wood and not a more dense product. Time (many many years) x wood quality x poor finish applications = your table.

Comment: you've worn off or diluted the stain, that's all.

Comment: yes growth mean its getting worse -). I dont keep anything there at all.It happened once i think

Comment: i am more worried about the white discoloration on top right , which seems to be extending

Answer (score 1):

Clearly the bottom of a round object is damaging the table/finish. What that object is likely to be only you would know - bottom of a candlestick, a mug, or whatever round object is frequently/usually placed in the location with the damaged ring that's about the size of the ring.

Stopping further damage is as easy as using a coaster or placemat under the object, whatever it is.

Fixing the damage may involve refinishing the entire top of the table. Some smaller scale fix may or may not produce an acceptable-to-you result.

It appears that a dark stain has been damaged enough to reveal lighter wood below in several spots. Those would need to be re-stained to match the rest. It also appears that the finish is very "open grain" and that may be hard to restore as it was (*it would also drive **me** nuts trying to clean a dining table with that finish.*) I'd probably refinish with the intent of filling the grain for a smooth surface I could easily wipe clean, but my taste may not match yours, so that part is opinion, not the only way to do it. You could fix the stain and just coat over the areas of damaged finish, limiting the amount of finish applied to minimize filling of the grain, and attempt to match the surrounding finish. If the match proves unacceptable, you'll probably need to do the whole top, so it matches.

Comment: Thanks for ur suggestions. I don't remember putting anything there. but the ring suggest otherwise. Need to fix it without doing the whole table. I dont think it is an option. But yes finish will be challenges.I was hoping to get a good stain. But looks like it is also not possible

Comment: @joseph please take the [tour] to learn the proper way to say "thanks" here. (Hint - see the up arrow next and check mark near the top of the answer?)